# MagicalRecords importValuesForKeysWithObject mapping relationships

Tags: ios, magicalrecord

I have two NSManagedObjects

Team and Player

Each team contains many players and each player contains one team.

I am using `importValuesForKeysWithObject` method for mapping my entities.

At first I create a team:

```
Team *team = [Team MR_createEntity];
[team MR_importValuesForKeysWithObject:dictionary];
```

from NSDictionary:

```
{
    name = Chicago;
    teamID = 10;
}
```

Then I create a player:

```
Player *player = [Player MR_createEntity];
[player MR_importValuesForKeysWithObject:dictionary];
```

from NSDictionary:

```
{
    name = Alex;
    playerID = 23;
    teamID = 10;
}
```

I suppose that the magical import should know how to map relationships between the player and concrete team.

I use relatedByAttribute key in user info for the team relationship. I suppose that the magical import will try to find this id using key and compare it with existed team in database and then attach the player to the found team.

But I thing I set something wrong. Because the team is nil for the player after mapping.

This is how I set the key on the picture below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you need to put that particular relatedByAttribute on the entity, not the relationship.

Comment: but which entity. I ask with describing more http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22066656/magicalrecords-import-data-from-json-nsdictionary-import-relationships

Comment: Try the Player entity

Comment: can you see my second question? really tank you for the good framework!)

Comment: I just solved it, I miss one thing. I have answered here maybe it will help someone what do you think? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22066656/magicalrecords-import-data-from-json-nsdictionary-import-relationships